# Types: (Num a, Ord a) versus (Int a)?

Tags: haskell

In a file, I'm trying to define a function like this:

```
myReplicate :: (Int a) => a -> b -> [b]  
myReplicate n x  
    | n <= 0    = []  
    | otherwise = x : myReplicate (n-1) x
```

But when I try loading the file into ghci, I get this error:

```
ghci>:l 1.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 1.hs, interpreted )

1.hs:38:17:
    `Int' is applied to too many type arguments
    In the type signature for `myReplicate':
      myReplicate :: Int a => a -> b -> [b]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

ghci tells me that the type of myReplicate should be:

```
ghci>:t myReplicate 
myReplicate :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a1 -> [a1]
```

If I change the type declaration to what ghci recommends:

```
myReplicate :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> b -> [b]
```

...then the function compiles and 'works'.  However, it 'works' like this:

```
ghci>myReplicate 3.2 1
[1,1,1,1]
```

Why can't I declare that myReplicate only takes an Int as the first argument (also in light of the fact that Int descends(?) from the Ord class)?  I guess I could change my first guard to be x < 1, so that myReplicate 3.2 1 would produce [1, 1, 1,], but why do I have to bother with floats?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Int is a type, not a typeclass. What you want is

```
myReplicate :: Int -> b -> [b]
```

or probably more precisely

```
myReplicate :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
```

Here is a good tutorial on types and typeclasses: http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses

Comment: That's where the example comes from, albeit later on in the Recursion section.  In any case, as far as I know I am supposed to declare "type constraints" using the syntax: (SomeType a) =>, and I want to declare a type constraint of Int that applies to the first parameter variable.

Comment: Yep, but `Int` is a type, not a typeclass. The closest typeclass is probably `Integral`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't pick up on the distinction between types and typeclasses when specifying a "type/class constraint".  It seems like they should be only known as "typeclass constraints".  Thanks.

Comment: @7stud: The language is a little misleading—they’re called “type constraints” because they’re constraints *on* types (by typeclasses), not constraints *of* types (by annotations).

Comment: @7stud There's no need to use a concrete type to constrain a type variable; you don't declare a type to be type variable `a` and then constrain the `a` to be `Int`, you just declare the type to be `Int` in the first place.

Comment: "They’re called “type constraints” because they’re constraints on types (by typeclasses)".  I understand now.  When you write the type of a function like this [a] -> a, then 'a' stands for _any_ type.  But if you specify a constraint for the function, for instance:  (Eq a) => [a] -> a, then you have _constrained the type_ 'a' from _any type_ to only those types that implement the functions specified in Eq.  Hence, you have specified a _type constraint_ on 'a'.