# Type Signature error Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is probably a dumb question but I would like to understand type signatures better and why I am getting the following error when I run my code. Code is below.

```
area :: Double d => d -> d
area x = x^2 * 3.14
```

The error I am getting is below.

```
Double is applied to too many type arguments
In the type signature for `area': area :: Double d => d -> d
```

Comment: `Double` is a `type`, but you're using it as if it were a `typeclass`. See [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses).

Comment: Ok that helped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\`String' is applied to too many type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018959/string-is-applied-to-too-many-type-arguments), [Types: (Num a, Ord a) versus (Int a)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329408/types-num-a-ord-a-versus-int-a).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature you want is `Double -> Double`.

`Double d => d -> d` says “I take a value of any type `d`, and return a value of that same type, provided that `d` has an instance of a typeclass called `Double`”. The compiler is looking for a *typeclass* called `Double` but there is no such typeclass; instead it finds a *type* called `Double`, giving an error.

With some extensions (such as `TypeFamilies` or `GADTs`) you *can* write this type like so:

```
(d ~ Double) => d -> d
```

This says “I take a value of any type `d`, and return a value of that same type, provided that `d` is equal to `Double`”. That’s just a roundabout way of saying `Double -> Double`; if you write a function of this type, the compiler will actually expand it out to `Double -> Double`:

```
> :set -XTypeFamilies
> let f :: (d ~ Double) => d -> d; f x = x
> :t f
f :: Double -> Double
```

More technically, the error you’ve encountered is a *kind* error—kinds are the “types of types” and are used to check things like giving the correct number of type parameters to a type. Because you give a type parameter to `Double`, GHC infers that it should be a typeclass like `Eq` or `Ord` that takes 1 type as an argument (kind `* -> Constraint`), but `Double` is a plain type that takes no arguments (kind `*`). You can see the kinds of common types & typeclasses in GHCi with the `:kind` or `:k` command to get a better understanding of them:

```
> :k Double
Double :: *

> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *

> :k Maybe Double
Maybe Double :: *

> :k Eq
Eq :: * -> Constraint
```

Comment: I find all the talk about kinds in this answer superfluous and probably pretty confusing for the OP, considering the basic level of the question.

Comment: @luqui: I found it helpful to learn about kinds pretty early on in my Haskell journey, but I appreciate that it may not be equally helpful to everybody. I’ve split that information into a separate section and added more explanation in the hope that it’s clearer, at least.